# How does the coverage.so works?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to understand how ruby's internal library [coverage.so](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/coverage/rdoc/Coverage.html) works. By "works", I do not mean the usage of it. I mean how this calculates the line's execution count. I went through the source but, looks like after some method calls it's beyond my understanding.

Here's what I went through:

- [Module source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/ext/coverage/coverage.c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `coverage.so` module just connects to ruby core to get information, search for `rb_get_coverages()` function to get this https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/38ea561319864fecf92bc61af0d9b9b1f49df6a0/thread.c

```
VALUE
rb_get_coverages(void)
{
    return GET_VM()->coverages;
}

void
rb_set_coverages(VALUE coverages)
{
    GET_VM()->coverages = coverages;
    rb_add_event_hook(update_coverage, RUBY_EVENT_COVERAGE, Qnil);
}
```

And this file does the increments (`count = old_count +1`):

```
static void
update_coverage(rb_event_flag_t event, VALUE proc, VALUE self, ID id, VALUE klass)
{
    VALUE coverage = rb_iseq_coverage(GET_THREAD()->cfp->iseq);
    if (RB_TYPE_P(coverage, T_ARRAY) && !RBASIC_CLASS(coverage)) {
    long line = rb_sourceline() - 1;
    long count;
    if (line >= RARRAY_LEN(coverage)) { /* no longer tracked */
        return;
    }
    count = FIX2LONG(RARRAY_AREF(coverage, line)) + 1;
    if (POSFIXABLE(count)) {
        RARRAY_ASET(coverage, line, LONG2FIX(count));
    }
    }
}
```

Actual hash created in parse.y https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/4c4f809e932417137d06e334d79065a4849dda0b/parse.y#L5491

```
static VALUE
coverage(VALUE fname, int n)
{
    VALUE coverages = rb_get_coverages();
    if (RTEST(coverages) && RBASIC(coverages)->klass == 0) {
    VALUE lines = n > 0 ? rb_ary_tmp_new_fill(n) : rb_ary_tmp_new(0);
    rb_hash_aset(coverages, fname, lines);
    return lines;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was stuck at `return GET_VM()->coverages;`

Comment: @avellable, coverage in interpreters is part of core: there is interpreter loop - take next instruction from bytecode (or from ast) and execute actions of it. It this loop we can just find the line of instruction and increment execution count of the line. `update_coverage` (+1) called from .. `rb_add_event_hook(update_coverage, RUBY_EVENT_COVERAGE, Qnil);` .. https://github.com/ruby/ruby/search?q=RUBY_EVENT_COVERAGE .. https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/4c4f809e932417137d06e334d79065a4849dda0b/compile.c#L253 ok, there is special handler of `(event) == RUBY_EVENT_LINE` event when cov is enabled.

Comment: `ADD_TRACE(ret, line, RUBY_EVENT_LINE);` inserted by `iseq_compile_each()` https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/4c4f809e932417137d06e334d79065a4849dda0b/compile.c#L3857 `if (node->flags & NODE_FL_NEWLINE)` - so, on newline there is trace code emitter